# How to show pressed orange over an ImageView?

Tags: android

I sized the rel layout absolutely to 50dp, and only the parts outside the image are showing, so the image is blocking the pressed state...how to get the effect that I want? And FYI, putting the background directly on the ImageView changes nothing; the pressed orange is still underneath.

```
<RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_orange"
                    android:clickable="true" >
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/preview_plus"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/plus_button" /> 
                </RelativeLayout>
```

and btn_orange.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <color android:color="#66ffb300"/> 
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: An image will more elaborate your question what you are trying to achieve

Comment: rephrase your question please, it is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must say you can use a (touch listner)
this how u use a touch listner

```
image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
```

find ur image first

Add a touch Listner to ur image

```
 image.setOnTouchListener(image_onTouch);
```

//Add a touch method which is by name image_onTouch

```
OnTouchListener image_onTouch=new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0,MotionEvent arg1){
        int iAction=arg1.getAction();

        if(iAction==0){
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
        }
        else{
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

// image 1 is ur image which u want 2 click
and image 2 is the image when you touch that image you have to make an another image in which background color do u wanna show and use it in the code

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_orange"
                    android:clickable="true" >
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/preview_plus"
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/plus_button" /> 
                </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Good idea, but the image still is "higher" and blocks the orange color